# Mysql: delete rows with different values

Tags: mysql

I want to delete rows for a list of strings that i have, using mysql.

Example:

```
---------------------
|    accounts       |
|-------------------|
|string | name | id |
|-------|------|----|
| strn1 |  bla | 3  |
|-------|------|----|
| strn2 | other| 5  |
|-------|------|----|
```

then i have strn1 and strn2

```
delete from `accounts` where `string`= ("strn1","strn2");
```

(It doesnt work)

Comment: See IN(). That's all.

Comment: thanks a lot! TO EVERYONE!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks a lot to [strawberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529673/strawberry)

I did:

```
DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `column` IN ('strng1', 'strng2');
```

That's It.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete from `accounts` where `string` in ('strn1','strn2');
```